# Override bundle action

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a project with `symfony 2` and im using a `SonataAdminBundle` for my backend. How can i override  a `dashboardAction()` to extend them for more features ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The routing configuration for this sonata admin can be found in

```
// vendor/bundles/Sonata/AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml
    <route id="sonata_admin_dashboard" pattern="/dashboard">
        <default key="_controller">SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard</default>
    </route>
```

Let say you have a bundle named 'My/AdminBundle' that holds the controller that should extend the dashboardActions. Then try the following:

1. Create a controller in /My/AdminBundle/Controller/CoreController.php

   ```
   namespace My\AdminBundle\Controller;

   use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
   use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CoreController as BaseCoreContBroller;

   class CoreController extends BaseCoreContBroller
   {

       public function dashboardAction()
       {
           // your custom code

           // call parent method
           parent::dashboardAction();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Open the bundle routing configuration file located /My/AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml (you might have different configuration format such as xml)

```
sonata_admin_dashboard:
     pattern:  /dashboard
     defaults: { _controller: MyAdminBundle:Core:dashboard }
```

1. Open the application routing configuration file and add the following after sonata configuration so that it will override it

```
admin:
    resource: '@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml'
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin

MyAdminBundle:
    resource: "@MyAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin
```

**Disclaimer** just so you know I have not used this in a project. I just check it locally and it worked. It is possible that this is not the best solution!

Hope this helps

Comment: It is rather strange that this solution works, because first matched route is executed in Symfony. I have not tried your example though.

Comment: Thanks for nice solution ! If we put out dashboard routing over the sonata admin, this may works.

Comment: How do I pass parameter to the view through the custom method `dashboardAction`?